# C# Array list with class

Tags: java, c#, linq

I have the following C# class:

```
public class pageViews
{
    public string dateTime {get; set;}
    public string IPAddress {get; set;}
    public string Page {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}
}
```

and the following arraylist:

```
List <pageViews> pviews = new List<pageViews>();
```

I then make an instance of the class `pageViews` and populate the fields like so:

```
pageViews views = new pageViews();

views.dateTime = reader["DateTime"].ToString();
views.IPAddress = reader["IPAddress"].ToString();
views.Page = reader["Page"].ToString();
```

I then try and add the class to the arraylist like so:

```
pviews.add(views);
```

But I get the following error:

> CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not
>   contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

From what I have read, I should be using linq, which I already am:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Configuration; 
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

So what am I missing, as from what I can see I have all I need?

Comment: You need a capital letter for `Add` in C#

Comment: @Baldrick is right. you could solve this in the future by using **CTRL** + **SPACE** for auto completion while coding

Comment: @JossefHarush I am using notepad. I think it is good to develop my understanding by not using all these short cuts every where, but I appreciate your comment

Comment: @user4420358, please use a proper IDE :) like visual studio in your case. you would thank me. i guarantee it

Comment: @JossefHarush, again, I thank you for your advice, but I do not think you have understood the point of the exercise. IDE's encourage so many short cuts, you often do not see some of the information that helps to improve your understanding of the practices you work with. I use an IDE every day, but am using notepad for this exercise. Please see my other questions for what I have learnt from doing so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
pviews.add(views);
```

with

```
pviews.Add(views);
```

In C#, the `List.Add` method starts with a capital A.

See the Microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Problem on `add`. Use `Add` instead of `add`.
Try:

```
 pviews.Add(views);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Replace add with Add

Like:- `pviews.add(views); to pviews.Add(views);`